# Intent with action view does not have permission to view file

Tags: android, file, android-intent

I'm trying to view/open a couple of files I've downloaded to the app storage, but for some reason the spawned action-view activity does not have permission to open the file. Below the `fileEntity.getFile()` returns a File instance.

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(fileEntity.getFile());
Debugger.message("Viewing file of type " + file.mime + " at " + uri);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, fileEntity.mime);
startActivity(intent);
```

Outputs:

> 10:44:10.161  5660    com.app VERBOSE Message Viewing file of type application/pdf at file:///data/user/0/com.app/files/1_lol.pdf
>
> 10:44:10.421  2551    #2551   ERROR   DisplayData openFd: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Permission denied
>
> 10:44:10.421  2551    #2551   ERROR   PdfLoader   Can't load file (doesn't open)  Display Data [PDF : 1_lol.pdf] +FileOpenable, uri: file:///data/user/0/com.app/files/1_lol.pdf

This is how I save the file originally, which seem to work:

```
File file = fileEntity.getFile();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
HttpResponse response = getClient().rawRequest(fileEntity.url);

response.getEntity().writeTo(fos);
response.getEntity().consumeContent();
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

The problem is that the file once downloaded can't be opened.

Am I missing something, or have I not understood how internal storage works?

I have these permissions in android manifest;

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Edit** So, from all the examples in the android documentation I failed to find any resources about the `FileProvider` in the appcompat library. Following the [instructions here](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.html) helped solving the issue.

Comment: `file:///data/user/0/com.app` is private app storage

Comment: @Selvin Yes, that was what I was aiming for. However I didn't think that would prevent i.e PDF documents from being viewed if I instantiate the action intent.

Comment: use file provider...

Comment: @Selvin Thank you, that definitely seems like the solution. I'm updating my question once I've tested it.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you don't have permissions to open file is because you didn't grant other apps to open or view the file on your intent. To grant other apps to open the downloaded file, include the flag(as shown below):  FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
browserIntent.setDataAndType(getUriFromFile(localFile), "application/pdf");
browserIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION|
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

And for function: getUriFromFile

```
private Uri getUriFromFile(File file){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        return Uri.fromFile(file);
    }else {
        return FileProvider.getUriForFile(itemView.getContext(), itemView.getContext().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
    }
}
```